# Does too many users in salesforce org impact salesforce performance.How does it impact?

Tags: apex, trigger, configuration, sharing-rule

If a salesforce org has more than 150k users does it impact the Salesforce performance ? And in what scenarios . How do we approach these performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many users as you'd like without any real consequence to the database, but you'll want to read [Designing Record Access for Enterprise Scale](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/draes.pdf). It's more important that you design security to be as simple as possible so sharing tables can be updated efficiently. The general topics covered are:

> - Group Membership Operations and Sharing Recalculation
> - Object Relationships, Bulk Loading, and Sharing Recalculation
> - Tools for Large-Scale Realignments

This document provides tips for optimizing groups, sharing, and some special features you can request if you need better performance.